# How to shift pictures on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to shift my pictures to the left using jQuery. I am using a while statement to change all pictures. Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript">
 $(function() {
 $("#leftButton").click(function() {
   var imglength = $("#content").children("img").length;
   var iterations = imglength;
   var lastimg = imglength-1;
   var nextimg = lastimg-1;
   var start = 1;
   var text = "";
   document.getElementById("Number").innerHTML="The number of pictures is " + imglength;    
   document.getElementById("Number1").innerHTML="The index of the last image is " + lastimg;    

   while (start < iterations) 
      {
       var last = $("img:eq('lastimg')").attr("src");
       var next = $("img:eq('nextimg')").attr("src");
       text += "<br>Iteration: " + imgindex + " and nextimg is:" +nextimg;
       $("img:eq('lastimg')").attr('src', next);
       start++;
       nextimg--;  
      }
      document.getElementById("Number2").innerHTML = text;
   })
  })   
</script>
```

HTML is here:

## Imgae Shift

Left Shift
         Pictures

```
     <p id="Number">Number</p>
     <p id="Number1">Number</p>
     <p id="Number2">Number</p>

     <div id="result"></div> 
    </section>
  </section>
<footer>
  &copy; Matthew King: 2015, Birmingham, AL 35211
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the problem? What exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: The code seems to run but my images do not change their sources. Each iteration creates a output to the DOM but my images do not move. I am trying to move all my images to the left starting with the last image. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you also show the `HTML`? What is element with `ID` `Number3` ?

Comment: Just submitted html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to simply append the first image back to its parent.  This *should* remove it and add it back as the last child. In the demo, each image has a border so you can see what is happening.  I am guessing this is what you are after, but if not let me know.

```js
function slideKittens(){
  var first = document.querySelector("#kittens > img");
  first.parentNode.appendChild(first);
}

setInterval(slideKittens, 1 * 1000);
```

```css
#kittens img {
  border: solid 2px black;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="kittens" style="overflow: hidden; width:333px; height: 108px">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" style="border-color: black;" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" style="border-color: red;" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" style="border-color: green;" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" style="border-color: blue;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not use the variables correctly.

The lines

```
var last = $("img:eq('lastimg')").attr("src");
var next = $("img:eq('nextimg')").attr("src");
$("img:eq('lastimg')").attr('src', next);
```

should be

```
var last = $("img:eq('" + lastimg + "')").attr("src");
var next = $("img:eq('" + nextimg+ "')").attr("src");
$("img:eq('" + lastimg +"')").attr('src', next);
```